# custom status button in joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

The Joomla `com_content` has small toggle button for the article's status "publish" to publish or unpublish the articles. So, I want to have same type of toggle button in my component also to approve or disapprove users.

Now, I want some advice from experts on how to go about. I have gone through `com_content` but I don't really understand that how should i  begin. I can't understand `com_content` approach and code because I am not coding in line with Joomla 2.5.

How should I start with this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i made it work on my own. let me share the experience for those who will need it in future. my table field or database field is ***approved*** and its value is ***0*** initially (which means the record is unapproved by the admin)

in my layout/default page i have the code as below for the toggle button:

```
    <?php
    $k = 0;
    for ($i=0, $n=count( $this->items ); $i < $n; $i++)
    {
       $row = &$this->items[$i];
    ..................
    ..................
    ?>
    ..................

    <td align="center">
       <?php echo JHtml::_('job.approve', $row->approved, $i); ?>
    </td>
```

Note that i've $row->approved which is my field from db. then i've job.approve for which i have created a job.php file and placed in helpers directory. the code for job.php is:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_content
 */
abstract class JHtmlJob
{
    /**
     * @param   int $value  The state value
     * @param   int $i
     */
    static function approve($value = 0, $i)
    {
        // Array of image, task, title, action
        $states = array(
            0   => array('disabled.png',    'approve',  'Unapproved',   'Toggle to approve'),
            1   => array('tick.png',        'unapprove',    'Approved',     'Toggle to unapprove'),
        );
        $state  = JArrayHelper::getValue($states, (int) $value, $states[1]);
        $html   = JHtml::_('image', 'admin/'.$state[0], JText::_($state[2]), NULL, true);
        //if ($canChange) {
            $html   = '<a href="#" onclick="return listItemTask(\'cb'.$i.'\',\''.$state[1].'\')" title="'.JText::_($state[3]).'">'
                    . $html.'</a>';
        //}

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Then i've registered two tasks in controller as approve and unapprove along with approve function:

```
public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

        $this->registerTask('unapprove', 'approve');
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle the featured setting of a list of articles.
     *
     * @return  void
     * @since   1.6
     */
    function approve()
    {
        // Initialise variables.
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $ids    = JRequest::getVar('cid', array(), '', 'array');
        $values = array('approve' => 1, 'unapprove' => 0);
        $task   = $this->getTask();
        $value  = JArrayHelper::getValue($values, $task, 0, 'int');

        if (empty($ids)) {
            JError::raiseWarning(500, JText::_('JERROR_NO_ITEMS_SELECTED'));
        }
        else {
            // Get the model.
            $model = $this->getModel('jobs');

            // Publish the items.
            if (!$model->approve($ids, $value)) {
                JError::raiseWarning(500, $model->getError());
            }
        }

        $redirectTo = JRoute::_('index.php?option='.JRequest::getVar('option'));
        $this->setRedirect($redirectTo);
    }
```

Thereafter, i've added the following function in model to update the value to 0 or 1.

```
function approve($cid, $publish) {

         if (count( $cid ))
         {
             JArrayHelper::toInteger($cid);
             $cids = implode( ',', $cid );
             $query = 'UPDATE #__tbljobs'
                   . ' SET approved = '.(int) $publish
                   . ' WHERE id IN ( '.$cids.' )';
                  $this->_db->setQuery( $query );
                if (!$this->_db->query()) {
                    $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
                    return false;
                 }
           }
           return true;
 }
```

Please don't forget to include the job.php file in your view/view.html.php file as below:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

require_once JPATH_COMPONENT .'/helpers/job.php';

Class JobsViewListJobs extends JView
{
```

And remember i am not using JForm nor my code is in joomla 1.7 style. But i am following the MVC architecture. So, i am not sure if my method will work for people who are coding in joomla 1.7 and above style.

Comment: I had to add public function unapprove() { $this->approve(); } to controller. Works perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to create publish button [Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJHtmlJGrid/published)-

```
JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $item->state, $i, 'articles.', $canChange);
```

Or this html-

```
<?php if($item->approve){?>
<td class="center">
    <a class="jgrid hasTip" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return listItemTask('cb<?php echo $i?>','items.disapprove')" title=""><span class="state publish"><span class="text">Disapprove</span></span></a>
</td>
<?php }else{?>
<td class="center">
    <a class="jgrid hasTip" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return listItemTask('cb<?php echo $i?>','items.approve')" title=""><span class="state unpublish"><span class="text">Approve</span></span></a>
</td>
<?php }?>
```

In `items.approve` and `items.disapprove` ,`items is controller` and `approve and 
  disapprove` is task of items controller.`

In your controller add these function-

```
public function __construct($config = array()){
                parent::__construct($config);
                $this->registerTask('unapproved', 'approved');
}
function approved() { 
    $ids = JRequest::getVar('cid', array(), '', 'array'); 
    JArrayHelper::toInteger($ids );
    $cids = implode( ',', $ids); 
    $values = array('approved' => 1, 'unapproved' => 0); 
    $task = $this->getTask(); 
    $value = JArrayHelper::getValue($values, $task, 0, 'int');      
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();      
    $query = 'UPDATE #__tbljobs' . ' SET approved = '.(int) $value . ' WHERE id IN ( '.$cids.' )';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->query();
    $redirectTo = JRoute::_('index.php?option='.JRequest::getVar('option').'&task=display'); 
    $this->setRedirect($redirectTo); 
}
```

Read this - [Joomla 2.5 extend jgrid.published column in custom component](http://joomla-answers.blogspot.in/2012/06/joomla-25-extend-jgridpublished-column.html)

Hope this will help.

Comment: @RaamanRai The `jgrid.published`does work if you use the tasks `publish` and `unpublish`. It can even work automatically if you are using a `JControllerAdmin` and create a column alias for the `published` column.